# Cant get Flandmarks to work, C++, Error LNK2019, Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, unresolved-external

I want to test Flandmarks for face detection 
http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/ But I cant get it to work.

I've been working on this for probably 10 hours.
I asked for help on opencv.org (http://answers.opencv.org/question/16956/eye-detection-is-jumping/ , the question were first about something else, see comments if you want to read what was said about this problem) And got some help but the problem is still there.

Computer: 64bit, windows 7, Visual studio 2010.

What I've tried:

Due to this problem i was asked to try with an empty project so I did that.

I started an empty project in visual studio c++ 2010. 
Property manager-> Added under C/C++ -> Additional include directories:

```
* C:\Program Files (x86)\opencv\build\include
* C:\Program Files (x86)\opencv\build\include\opencv
* C:\Program Files (x86)\opencv\build\include\opencv2
```

Property manager-> LInker -> Additional include directories ->

```
* C:\Program Files (x86)\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib;
* C:\Program Files (x86)\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin; 
* %(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

Property Manager -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies ->

```
* opencv_calib3d244d.lib
* opencv_contrib244d.lib
* opencv_core244d.lib
* opencv_features2d244d.lib
* opencv_flann244d.lib
* opencv_gpu244d.lib
* opencv_haartraining_engined.lib
* opencv_highgui244d.lib
* opencv_imgproc244d.lib
* opencv_legacy244d.lib
* opencv_ml244d.lib
* opencv_nonfree244d.lib
* opencv_objdetect244d.lib
* opencv_photo244d.lib
* opencv_stitching244d.lib
* opencv_ts244d.lib
* opencv_video244d.lib
* opencv_videostab244d.lib
```

Property manager -> COnfiguration manager -> ACtive Solution platform ->

- Changed from win32 to "new", where I changed from Itanium To x64. Copy settings from "win32"

From the zip-file that you can download at flandmarks homepage, I copy the files in the folder "libflandmark". to my project folder. And I also copy the dat-file to the project folder.

```
* flandmark_detector.cpp
* flandmark_detector.h
* liblbp.cpp
* liblbp.h
* msvc-compat.h
* flandmark_model.dat
```

I created a main.cpp where I added:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "flandmark_detector.h"


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{ 
    printf("test");
    FLANDMARK_Model * model = flandmark_init("flandmark_model.dat");

    return 0;
}
```

After this the error is:

```
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct model_struct * __cdecl flandmark_init(char const *)" (?flandmark_init@@YAPEAUmodel_struct@@PEBD@Z) referenced in function main
1>C:\projects\test_projects\flandmarks_empty\x64\Debug\flandmarks_empty.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:04.47
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Try surrounding the #include of the flandmark header file with 'extern "C" { }', then do a fresh rebuild.

Comment: I tried user2585483s solution and it worked, but I am curious what 'extern "C"{}' do? If you have time, please explain. Thank you for taking your time to help me!

Comment: Good news that it worked using the suggestion in the answer.  I had thought it might be related to 'extern "C" {}' because it looked like a name mangling issue.  When mixing C and C++ code the compiler will mangle C function names.  'extern "C" {}' will tell it not to mangle the C function names within this declaration.

Comment: Hi @Mattias. I am also trying to implement flandmark detector in opencv and c++. I tried following the steps mentioned here but I get build error and on the output screen is written: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cv.h': No such file or directory. Could you guide me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is looking for flandmart_init(char const *). You need to include the header file that defined this function. If you have already included its header file then the compiler cannot find where the function flandmart_init() was defined. Now if you have flandmark_detector.cpp and flandmark_model.cpp as this looks like a third party code. Include both their header files and after that include on your project flandmark_model.cpp and flandmark_model.cpp, whichever defined the function flandmart_init(char const *). Make sure it compiles. Add them together with your .cpp files. You can right click the Source Files on your project, then click; Add->Existing Item.

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot to add the files in the project. I only copied the files to the project folder. Thank you thank you! You are my savior!