# Flandmark detector not working in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

I am using opencv 2.4.2 and C++. I am trying to implement flandmarker detector in C++ and came across this post [Cant get Flandmarks to work, C++, Error LNK2019, Unresolved external symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735244/cant-get-flandmarks-to-work-c-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol) . I tried doing the same,that is, I added the Additional Include Directories under C/C++ and Linker,added the additional dependencies under Input and download this file https://codeload.github.com/uricamic/flandmark/zip/master from the flandmarker website,extracted those files and put them in my project folder. I even did what @dervish said below. But still I get the error below [image]. Also if I do not include the opencv_***244d.lib files in the linker I get this error [image].I searched for those opencv_***244d.lib files on my pc but could not find any. I really need to get this working. Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: You probably dont have cv.h in the right place...

Comment: the cv.h file header is there. It is in this folder C:\opencv\build\include\opencv

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Unless OpenCV is installed in a standard location (and apparently it's not), you need to let your IDE know where to find the include directory.

Comment: i am using Microsoft visual studio 2010 ultimate and c++

Comment: Please copy the error messages in the question. Its easier for us to read, the image might vanish not the text and text can be indexed. Your error messags says, that the library is not found. Similar to your include directory, you have to add the library. I don't know how this is done with Visual Studio.

Comment: now the path to the opencv libs is missing in the linker settings. @Steph, you had some other projects successfully running with opencv before, right ? look at how the opencv libs got integrated there.

Comment: @user2799037 : I did a search on my pc for this file and could not find it. It is the case also for the other opencv_***244d.lib files. And hence I do not know where to find them in order to include them.

Comment: Could you use CMake to generate your project files..? It will take all the guesswork out of the include directories and you can concentrate on the important stuff. For reference, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334254/link-opencv-2-4-6-with-qt-library/20335513#20335513). Also, it seems like the flandmarker has provided CMakeLists. I strongly advise you to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also using the same library to detect facial feature points recently.

You can make it work by following the follwowing steps:

3. Make sure you add the correct **`OpenCV-Path\build\include`** and **`OpenCV-Path\build\x86\vc10\lib`** (all OpenCV libs you added to your project should be found here) to the project.
4. For `liblbp.h` file, change

   ```
   #include "msvc-compat.h"
   ```

   to

   ```
   #include <stdint.h>
   ```
5. For `flandmark_detector.h` file, change

   ```
   #include "msvc-compat.h"
   #include <cv.h>
   #include <cvaux.h>
   ```

   to

   ```
   #include <stdint.h>

   #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

   #include <iostream>
   #include <stdio.h>

   using namespace std;
   using namespace cv;
   ```

---

***You can download the workable VS10 project of this library [here](https://bitbucket.org/herohuyongtao/files/downloads/flandmark-vs10-new.zip).***

Note: I also added the OpenCV library in the project so that it should run well without any extra setting.

After running this, you should achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: I did as you said. However,I removed all the opencv_***244d.lib from the linker. I did a search on my pc for those files and could not find any. I now get this error http://i.imgur.com/Rfku9bs.jpg .

Comment: @Steph You have add needed `.lib` files in order to work well.

Comment: @Steph These `.lib` files are under `OpenCV-Path\build\x86\vc10\lib`.

Comment: yes I know,but there are only opencv_***242d and opencv_***242 files in this path. There are no opencv_***244d.lib files. In this post stackoverflow.com/questions/17735244/… the person added opencv_***244d.lib files also in Property Manager -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies -> for it to work. Also I already did the first step

Comment: @Steph This is just the difference of OpenCV of different versions. You can just use all `242` instead of `244`.

Comment: ok!but still not working..I am getting the errors: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol and this fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals as in the 2nd picture above

Comment: @Steph I updated the answer by adding the workable project with proper setting. You can run it without any extra setting.

Comment: @Steph Please simply run the project I shared without any setting. It should work.

Comment: I am desperately trying to run your project without any setting. I just extracted the file and double clicked the Microsoft Visual Studio Solution opencv_2.4.2_x64. It opens in Visual studio but tells me "Unable to start program....the system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: @Steph Did you rebuild? Right click -> clean and rebuild.

Comment: Yes I did it..I get fatal error C1083: Cannot open type library file: 'msxml3.dll': No such file or directory,lots of warnings and Build FAILED

Comment: @Steph Please replace the `main.cpp` with [this one](https://bitbucket.org/herohuyongtao/files/downloads/main.cpp). And check how it goes (rebuild).

Comment: I tried changing the picture which was in the folder(lenna.jpg) and put one of mine and changed the name os argv[1] in main. It still detects lenna.jpg :s

Comment: @Steph And don't forget to also change this line `argv[1] = "lenna.jpg";`.

Comment: yess :D I had to delete lenna.jpg though. I tried it with this picture http://i.imgur.com/NtagnwZ.jpg. It detects points outside the face area,like this http://i.imgur.com/RGD6xZu.jpg

Comment: @Steph You have to also change `argv[2-5]`, which are the `[x1,y1,x2,y2]`, i.e. bounding box of the face. Here I set it in the code just to show how to setup this library. You can use face detection result instead.

Comment: can we move that to chat please?

Comment: @Steph It always fail when I try to move to chat. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: ok no problem!The thing is each time I change a picture,I need to change [x1,y1,x2,y2]. I wanted to make it detect landmarks from my webcam,just as in the video on this website http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/

Comment: @Steph As I have said, you can cooperate the face detection result to automatically compute these four values.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the file `flandmark_detector.h`, replace

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cvaux.h>
```

by

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/cvaux.h>
```

because those files have this path:

> `/opencvDIR/include/opencv`

Comment: I did as you said but now the error is exactly as in the post I mentioned in my question. When I do extern "C"{}, it does not work for me

Comment: for me i'm working on the same lib rightnow, I do not need to put  extern "C", just put the files in projectDIR, works fine !

Comment: Not a good idea. Especially this will not solve his linker problem.